# Laravel condition in URI

Tags: php, laravel, uri

I am planning to implement an api for a database using Laravel and I am hoping to have a search function using a URI like

www.exaample.com/WaferSearch?{search string}

It seems very easy to implement a search string like

param1 = 4

This would request a list of wafers ( this is what the database is about) where param1 is equal to 4

The documentation seems to be very clear about how I can turn any sort of a question like this into SQL.

However, I want to have a search string like

param1 > 4

I would also be happy to express the search string like this

param1_GreaterThan =4

and I can see how I could write some code to parse the search string to work out what was required.  However I feel that I would be solving a problem that must have been solved many times before.

Is there a well established way to do this?

Graham

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of ways to implement something like this but one way springs to mind as the most extensible. Use two variables in the query.

- Greater than
  `http://myapi.com/wafersearch?p1=4&op=gt`
- Less than
  `http://myapi.com/wafersearch?p1=4&op=lt`
- Equal to
  `http://myapi.com/wafersearch?p1=4&op=eq`

Alternatively you could use rewrites to pass in the variables directly to the route / controller method.

- Greater than
  `http://myapi.com/wafersearch/gt/4`
- Less than
  `http://myapi.com/wafersearch/lt/4`
- Equal to
  `http://myapi.com/wafersearch/eq/4`

Comment: Would you recommend to do `?p1=4&op1=gt` to support multiple parameters?

Comment: Yeah, it could easily be `?p1=4&p1op=gt&p2=2&p2op=lt` this way you only have one route handling all `wafersearch` calls with multiple params and different operators.

Comment: Thanks very much for that advice.  I think that I could use that.  The only worry that I have is that it could make the search string quite long if there were a large number of parameters, which under this scheme would have twice as many items in the search string. I am not quite sure how many parameters will be used at this stage,  but I think that I have read that there is a limit for GET operations.